# wireless connection with macbook pro

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi

I have a macbook pro (mid 2008). Right now I'm experiencing problems with the wireless connection at work. It goes on and off. Every time I loose the connection I have to turn Airport off and on again, and it works. But  this happens quite frequently.

The administrator says that he does not see network problems. Any idea of what could that be?

Comment: Does this happen on other computers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration and trash the com.apple.airport.preferences.plist file.

Reboot and a new file will be regenerated. This would eliminate a corrupt file.

If the problem persists, you may have some interference in your cube so moving any printers or other electronic devices further away might help.